# Error Undefined offset - How to correctly display the elements of my array in my PHP Code?

Tags: php

My method or function `recurseMenu` (in: `UssdNode.php`) normally contains **the list of menus** (***WHICH I LOOK TO DISPLAY***) contained in the variable `$title=$node->getTitle()`:

```
function recurseMenu($items,$bufferLimit) {
        $objectString="<strong>". $this->getTitle() . "</strong>" . PHP_EOL;
        $lastMenu=false;
        var_dump($items);           //DEBUG "items"
        if(count($items)>0) {
            for ($i = $this->index; $i <= $bufferLimit; $i++) {
                if ($items[$i]) {
                    $item = $items[$i];
                    $num = $i + 1;
                    // get node by name
                    $userSessions = $_SESSION['userSessions'];
                    $currUserSession = $userSessions[$this->address];
                    $node = $currUserSession->getNode($item);
                    $title = $node->getTitle();
                    $objectString .= PHP_EOL . $num . '. ' . $title;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $objectString=$objectString.PHP_EOL . 'NO DATA AVAILABLE, TRY AGAIN LATER';
        }
        $lastMenu=$bufferLimit==count($items);
        $objectString=$objectString . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . "<strong>0. Exit</strong>";
        if($this->getParent() != '0'){
            $objectString=$objectString . PHP_EOL . "<strong>#. Back</strong>";

        }
        if($lastMenu===false){
            $rem=count($items)-$this->index;
            $objectString=$objectString . PHP_EOL . "<strong>99. Next (".$rem.")</strong>";
        }
        return $objectString;
    }
```

**The `getNode` method of the `UssdTree.php` file**:

```
function getNode($name){
        $node=$this->treeMenu[$name];
        return $node;
    }
```

And **when I try the debug of** `$this->recurseMenu($items,$bufferLimit)` in my `toString` method or function which displays the list of `$title` as strings:

```
function toString(){
        $objectString='';
        $items=$this->children;
        $bufferLimit=(count($items)==0)?1:$this->getBufferLimit()+1;
 
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($this->recurseMenu($items,$bufferLimit));
        echo "</pre>";
 
        do{
            $bufferLimit-=1;
            $objectString=$this->recurseMenu($items,$bufferLimit);
        }while(strlen($objectString>160));
        $this->index=$bufferLimit;
        return $objectString;
    }
```

**So, the problem is that nothing is displayed. And I get the following error:**

- ***Line 86** of the error I get and put below is from the `UssdNode.php` file which contains the statement by `true` of the variable `if ($items[$i])` in the `recurseMenu` method below:*

> Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in C:\laragon\www\ussd\ussdmenu-server-php\UssdNode.php on line 86

**When I the debug of** `var_dump($items);` at the line **3** in my `recurseMenu` method or function above, I get this return:

```
array(4) {
[0]=>
string(5) "umeme"
[1]=>
string(4) "nwsc"
[2]=>
string(5) "paytv"
[3]=>
string(10) "paycurrent"
}
```

And when I edit `$bufferLimit` variable by removing the addition `+1` at `$this->getBufferLimit()+1` in the declaration of the variable `$bufferLimit=(count($items)==0)?1:$this->getBufferLimit()+1;` of the `toString` function, **the menus are displayed fine but it creates another lag when pressing or issuing the request for the `99. Next` key**.

**How to correctly display the list of menus represented by the variable `$title=$node->getTitle();` in the `recurseMenu` method below ?**

Help me fix this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", "Warning: Undefined array key", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-warning-undefined-arr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The displayed error says the following:

The array `$items` has four items, accessible by the keys `0, 1, 2 and 3`. But you are asking for key `4`. This key is not there. I don't know what to do, so I am giving you an error message.

You now have two possible ways to go.

1. Make sure that the index (`$i`) is never greater than the highest index of the array.

Maybe your logic with calculating `$bufferLimit` is wrong, or maybe the loop is not correct. Maybe `$i <= $bufferLimit` needs to be `$i < $bufferLimit`.

2. Check first to see if the key you are using is actually present in the array https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

`if ($items[$i])` would need to change to `if (array_key_exists($i, $items))`

That way you could keep your current logic of calculating `$this->index` and `$bufferLimit`, but if the asked key is not there, the if-statement will end up being false and not throw an error.